# ¿Cómo poner varios gráficos en una misma ventana en Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

para mi trabajo de grado tengo 1000 conjuntos de valores (en *Excel*) que deben ir graficados en una misma ventana, he intentado con un ciclo pero no me ha sido posible, genera un gráfico en ventanas diferentes.

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Paths = ["CENIZA_"+str(n)+".xlsx" for n in range(1, 1001)]

for i in Paths:

    doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)

    # Selecciona la hoja que se trabajará
    sheet = doc['Exported Data']

    # Se crean las listas a las que se le añadirán los valores de Excel
    Aceleraciones = []
    Periodos = []
    print(i)

    # Ciclo que recorre las filas
    # Ciclo para sismo de fuente cercana
    for Per, Ace in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=93, min_col=1, max_col=2):

        Periodos.append(Per.value)
        Aceleraciones.append(Ace.value)

    plt.figure()
    x = Periodos
    y = Aceleraciones
    plt.plot(x, y, "r")
    plt.xlabel("Periodo [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Aceleración espectral Sa [m/s^2]")
    plt.title("Espectros de respuesta de aceleración")
    plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Este es el resultado del código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera como dije arriba generar, todos estos 1000 conjuntos de valores en una misma ventana (superpuestos), agradecería mucho la ayuda, es muy importante para mi tesis.

Necesito un resultado similar, a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a todos los conjuntos graficados en ese mismo grafico, con lineas de distinto color, tipo: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/_images/frame_plot_basic.png?

Comment: Exactamente, así, pueden ir con el mismo color, porque luego de eso necesito sacar la media y la desviación estándar de todos los 1000.

Comment: Richard te has planteado o puede usar [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), lo digo porque además de valerte para leer los xlsx, almacenar los datos en columnas y graficar usando matplotlib te permite operar mucho más eficientemente (por ejemplo calcular la media y la std de cada serie de datos es trivial (`std = df.std()`)

Comment: Si, me lo planteé, pero no se usar usar la librería además tengo menos de dos semana para entregar mi proyecto de grado. Agregué una imagen al post algo similar de lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1):

Fue posible solucionar la pregunta de la siguiente manera:

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



Paths = ["CENIZA_"+str(n)+".xlsx" for n in range(1, 3)]
SisFuente = []

for i in Paths:

    doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)

    # Selecciona la hoja que se trabajará
    sheet = doc['Exported Data']

    # Se crean las listas a las que se le añadirán los valores de Excel
    Aceleraciones = []
    Periodos = []
    print(i)

    # Ciclo que recorre las filas
    # Ciclo para sismo de fuente cercana
    for Per, Ace in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=93, min_col=1, max_col=2):

        Periodos.append(Per.value)
        Aceleraciones.append(Ace.value)

    Conjunto = [Periodos, Aceleraciones]
    SisFuente.append(Conjunto)


plt.figure()
for j in SisFuente:

    x = j[0]
    y = j[1]
    plt.plot(x, y, "r")
    plt.xlabel("Periodo [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Aceleración espectral Sa [m/s^2]")
    plt.title("Espectros de respuesta de aceleración")
    plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Debía de crear una lista con todos los valores, luego esos valores debía de graficarlos todos en un ciclo, pero antes del ciclo debería de ir `plt.figure()` para que estuviera todo en una misma ventana.